# How do I Generate a List of Connections Between VHDL Blocks?

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I want to generate a list of all the signal connections between high-level VHDL blocks in a VHDL file.

For example, this is what Quartus' RTL viewer does, but graphically.

I want my results to be textual instead of graphical, and to look something like this:

```
Block A:
input: block_a_instance_name.signal_name <- block_b_instance_name.signal_name
input: block_a_instance_name.signal_name <- block_c_instance_name.signal_name
output: block_a_instance_name.signal_name -> block_d_instance_name.signal_name

BLOCK B:
input: block_b_instance_name.signal_name <- block_b_instance_name.signal_name
input: block_b_instance_name.signal_name <- block_c_instance_name.signal_name
```

It doesn't have to look exactly like this, but it should convey this general high-level connection information.

Any way to do this with Quartus or other VHDL tools?

Answer (score 2):

That format doesn't look dissimilar to a standard VHDL port map. Should be able to get away with a quick Perl script for that.

Comment: What do you mean? How do you use a quick perl script to figure out which ports connect to which?

Comment: The vhdl explicitly connects up the blocks. You can create a perl script that reads in your VHDL files, and prints out the information you want.